# How can I unpack the two lists(list1 and list2) that are getting returned from the function common()?

Tags: python, list

The function `common()` returns two lists. I want to store the two lists in two different variables(say `result1` and `result2`). How do I do that?

I tried, `result1, result2 = common(a,b)`

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]      #1st input
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13] #2nd input
a_dup = []
b_dup = []
def common(list1,list2) :                    
    for x in list1 :                           
        if list1.count(x) == 1 :
            a_dup.append(x)
    return a_dup
    for x in list2 :
        if list2.count(x) == 1 :
            b_dup.append(x)
    return b_dup
result1, result2 = common(a,b)
```

It is giving the below error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: remove the other returns, and just put a `return a_dup, b_dup` at the end

Comment: You function returns only one list, because the second return statement is unreachable. The last 4 lines of the function will never run.

Comment: if you want `result1, result2 = common(a, b)` to work then remove `return a_dip` and change `return b_dup` to `return a_dup, b_dup`. your error means that the `common(a,b)` is returning one value but you are expecting it to return two values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a function returns a value, it stop any operation afterward. So, all codes after `return a_dup` are abandoned. If you mind to return both values at once, do this:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]      #1st input
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13] #2nd input
a_dup = []
b_dup = []
def common(list1,list2) :                    
    for x in list1 :                           
        if list1.count(x) == 1 :
            a_dup.append(x)
    for x in list2 :
        if list2.count(x) == 1 :
            b_dup.append(x)
    return a_dup, b_dup
result1, result2 = common(a,b)
```